# An edit missing from PostHistory in SEDE

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, data-explorer

I was looking at the revision history of the question "[Is all ordinary mathematics contained in high school mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/36580)" on MathOverflow ([revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/36580/revisions), [edit suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/165831)). I was curious what was actually the difference between the old and the new title - the revision history shows difference between the titles in the two revisions.

So I tried to check SEDE - to see what titles are shown in the `Text` field of the `PostHistory` table. Then I realized that the edit [isn't shown in the PostHistory table  at all](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1252003/posthistory-for-a-specific-post?id=36580) (among the entries for this post).

The edit was made on July 24 - the database was updated since then. (SEDE shows "Data updated 2 days ago". There were some problems with SEDE, but according to answer there, they should be resolved now: [Weekly SEDE refresh stuck at Gaming.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380857). When I check [the most recent post in database](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1623462), I see some posts made on July 31.)

Comment: It is super weird. The mathoverflow database is up to date as of last sunday: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1623469 and nothing obvious is wrong with the posthistory table either.

Comment: As for your underlying question: [a space was removed](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-guids#ids=d77bcf04-8174-4ab9-a9f6-c8a36a857aaa&filter=default&site=mathoverflow.net&run=true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is no fun.

The PostHistory table is fine.

[image: SEDE result with 6 rows and column userid instead of User Link]

All the records are there. Notice how UserId is no longer a magic link, User Link. Having the User Link magic column magically makes rows go up in smoke.

I tried to replace the User Link with the somewhat less magical manual link build option ([SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1623841/posthistory-for-a-specific-post)):

```
 case when userid is null then '?'
  else
     concat('site://users/'
           , UserId 
           , '|'
           , (select displayname 
              from users 
              where users.id = posthistory.userid))
   end [User],
```

and then I'm getting the result you and I expect.

[image: User column is linked]

So, to answer your question: No, there is no edit missing. Instead a SEDE feature that is supposed to make things a bit easier is playing confusing tricks on us. Now why it does that is something I go dig into next ...

In your original query you have:

```
UserId AS [User Link], UserDisplayName,
```

If I add a space after the `]` or move the whole `UserDisplayName,` to the next line:

```
UserId AS [User Link], 
UserDisplayName,
```

your original query works.

Comment: Great ... now I'm wondering how many queries are affected by this ...

Comment: @Glorfindel we can't know. We don't have access to stored queries except scraping. I suspect the problem is either in [QueryRunner](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/bc5b842e9e531602da74665a7d69462363bbd452/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/QueryRunner.cs) or in [ParsedQuery](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/bc5b842e9e531602da74665a7d69462363bbd452/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/ParsedQuery.cs) but none of the fail cases I imagine would lead to the query returning less rows.