# Weekly SEDE refresh has been contemplating Buddhism for a significant amount of time

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

[Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/) is interesting, surely, but either the weekly SEDE refresh has gained some [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) and is contemplating rebirth, or something is stuck. I'm not sure which one to hope for!

I'm looking at [rene's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) SEDE query [Status of the SEDE Refresh on Sunday 03:00 UTC](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc) to check the status, which is currently (in part):

| . | category | database_id | Description | create_date | days ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | restoring | 70 | StackExchange.Buddhism_Temp | 2022-09-18 04:08:56 | 0 |

... which is about 11 hours before the time of this posting.

Comment: Yeah, that is stuck.

Comment: We're working on this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, this appears to happen more and more often recently, and every time someone first reports it, then wait until a moderator adds the [tag:status-review] tag, then you guys doing awesome work of solving the case. Any chance this process can be simplified, e.g. automatic monitoring?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard To be clear, this meta post or any moderator action isn't what triggered us to work on this, in fact we were already working on it and one of us asked "I wonder if meta has a report yet?"

Comment: @Aaron oh, that's good to hear. That said, any update on the progress [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380907/152859)? :)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard This is the first thing we started working on when we came online on a Monday morning, given that we don't currently have an SLA for weekend/overnight response.

Comment: Stack Overflow finally finished on Sep 20 @ ~22:07 UTC.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have identified and resolved the root cause, which was related to a schema change on a base table that wasn't reflected in a view against that table.

Basically, [a string column involving review task comments was made wider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350360/165455), but the view that feeds SEDE still thought it was shorter. A comment in the review queue for `Buddhism` (which exceeded the old length) was entered in the meantime, but this incompatibility wasn't spotted because the only views against it are the ones for SEDE.

- `Buddhism` has been corrected manually and is now complete.
- We are currently kicking off the remainder of the databases, which will take about 8 hours. *Note: Stack Overflow takes the longest, and had a failure overnight, so finished Sep 20 @ ~22:07 UTC*.
- We have created a task internally to automatically refresh all SEDE-related views prior to the weekly refresh task.

Comment: That's awesome, it's really not trivial you put so much effort into SEDE. Thanks! :)